# How can I show the annotation point information on the map?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

*When I click Annotation on the map, I want the information about the clicked location to appear in the back view at the bottom.I used Mapkit to create the map*
[image: Image of the view I'm trying to make]

*Annotation Array*

```
  let annotationLocations = [
        
        ["title":"X vet Clinic","latitude":39.895177 , "longitude":32.838194],
        ["title":"Y Vet Clinic","latitude": 39.894749, "longitude":32.841074],
        ["title":"Z Vet Clinic","latitude":  39.893615, "longitude":32.841476]
      
    ]
```

*With this function, I can show the locations specified in the latitude longitudes above on the map*

```
 func createAnnotations(locations: [[String: Any]])
    {
        
        for location in locations{
           let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotations.title = location["title"] as? String
         
            annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude:  location["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
            myMap.addAnnotation(annotations)
            
        }
       
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass your annotation and put the required data in there;

```
class VetClinicAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    
    let name: String
    let address: String
    let image: UIImage
    
    init(with name: String, address: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.image = image
    }
    
}
```

Then you can get the annotation info from your map view delegate;

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? VetClinicAnnotation {
        // Use the annotation data
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the delegate

```
myMap.delegate = self
```

Then implement

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
   let ann = view.annotation as! MKPointAnnotation
   // use ann
}
```